# Clojure REPL environment lost after running refresh-all

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm hacking on a Clojure app I created with `lein new app inclojure`. There are a few things I'd like to pre-load every time I fire up the REPL, so I created a `dev/user.clj` file, and source it in my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject inclojure "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot inclojure.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}
             :dev {:source-paths ["dev"]}})
```

The file mostly just requires a bunch of crap so I can use shorthand:

```
(ns inclojure.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer (refresh-all)])
  (:use [clojure.reflect :only [reflect]]
        [clojure.pprint :only [pprint print-table pp]]))

(defn r
  "inspect all of the properties in a java object, optionally by specifying a
  pattern"
  ([o] (r o "."))
  ([o prefix]
    (->> (reflect o :ancestors true)
         :members
         (filter #(re-find (re-pattern (str "(?i)" prefix)) (str (:name %))))
         (pprint))))
```

This all works, but when I run `(refresh-all)`, it loses everything from `dev/user.clj`. Is there a way for me to be able to `(refresh-all)` from the and either keep or re-load everything from `dev/user.clj`?

It seems like I may want to create a REPL-specific namespace like `inclojure.repl` in `dev/user.clj`, and then make that the REPL's [`init-ns`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L301).